# ubuntu 16.04 dconf locks don't seem to work

Tags: gnome, 16.04, lock-screen, ibus

I looked at [dconf and locks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298533/dconf-and-locks) and I came up with this script to try to enforce screen locking.   It doesn't work.  I used to have this working under debian but can't seem to get it to work under ubuntu.   Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash -x
umask 0022
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/locks
printf "#Defaults set in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_charles.gschema.override
#Recompile schemas with:
# glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
#Update dconf with:
# dconf update
/org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-delay
" > /etc/dconf/db/ibus.d/locks/00-default-screen-lock

printf "[org.gnome.desktop.session]
idle-delay=900
[org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]
lock-enabled=true
lock-delay=60
" > /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_charles.gschema.override

glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
dconf update
```

Comment: I had a umask permission problem and I also changed my script to use local.d

Answer (score 2):

I had a umask permission problem and I also changed my script to use local.d

```
#!/bin/bash -x
# login as root to run this.  make sure umask is default setting

mkdir -p /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks

printf "#Defaults set in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_charles.gschema.override
#Recompile schemas with:
# glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
#Update dconf with:
# dconf update
/org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled
/org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-delay
" > /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00-default-screen-lock

printf "[org.gnome.desktop.session]
idle-delay=900
[org.gnome.desktop.screensaver]
lock-enabled=true
lock-delay=60
" > /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/60_charles.gschema.override

printf "user-db:user
system-db:local
" > /etc/dconf/profile/user

glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
dconf update
```